# Google Drive SDK: About parents of a file

Tags: google-drive-api

I've a question about the parents of a file. When I'm retrieving information about the parent with $file->getParents(), I'm receiving an array with the only element being the information about the parent.

My question is: for now, I've always only one parent but can a file get more parents? And if yes, in which case?

Thanks you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file can be logically part of multiple collections, you can consider them as labels that allow a hierarchy.
When a file belongs to multiple folders, the API will return their list when calling getParents().

Comment: Ok thanks, my Drve doesn't have subfolders in folders, which may explain why I didn't think about it.

Comment: How can a file be part of multiple collections?

Comment: Collections are more like labels than physical folders, so you can add multiple labels to the same file.