# Setting multiple parents for Google Drive File

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Read several SO posts (ex. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608759/google-drive-sdk-about-parents-of-a-file)) that allude to Google Drive files being able to have multiple parents, i.e. same file in multiple folders.   I wanted to test this out, as I am brainstorming ideas for backing up collections of files for my android app, without having to reload the entire collection on each backup.

Unfortunately, when i set the file metadata as such below, the file does not upload to either parent-folder.  It does upload and appear when I comment out one of the parents.

As a result, I assume that the ability to set multiple parents is reserved for special folders like "trash" or "favorites?"   Or do i need to try updating the file after initial creation?

```
    List<ParentReference> parents = new ArrayList<ParentReference>();
    parents.add(new ParentReference().setId(parentId1));
    parents.add(new ParentReference().setId(parentId2));


static private File create_File(String fileName, List<ParentReference> parents){

    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("db");

    System.out.println("Mimetype " + mimeType);

    // File's metadata.
    File file = new File();
    file.setMimeType(mimeType);
    file.setTitle(fileName);
    file.setParents(parents);

    return file;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

** May 2020 - See comment below. Google has decided to disallow multiple parents from September 2020 onward. This renders both the question and the answer stale**

**As a result, I assume that the ability to set multiple parents is reserved for special folders like "trash" or "favorites?"**

No. Any file can have multiple parents. You can try it easily at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#try-it

**Or do i need to try updating the file after initial creation?**

No. You can have multiple parents on creation.

It's a good idea to get into the habit of looking at the http requests that your app is sending and compare it with what you see at https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#try-it

You can enable http logging here https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#try-it

Comment: ok thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Some extra error checking, i found i was passing a bad second id.

Comment: This answer is old but for newcomers, Google has decided to move from "multiple parents" to a "shortcut" behaviour: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/simplifying-google-drives-folder-structure-and-sharing-models

Answer (score 1):

From the error messages I get in the API the limitation is with Team Drives or Shared Drives as per the error message from Google given below:

...?supportsAllDrives=true...

`403`

`"errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "teamDrivesParentLimit",
    "message": "A shared drive item must have exactly one parent."
   }`

Comment: In Google Drive Web UI when using Shift-Z:  "Files can't be added to shared drive, they must be moved"

Answer (score 0):

Multiple parents has been **no** longer allowed since **Sept 30, 2020**. You can now use [shortcuts](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts) to migrate or fix your issue.

Comment: any source????? Multiple parents in  https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#try-it  is still valid

Comment: @LukAron for v3, not v2